# How to remove option element in JQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this

```
<select id="zone" name="zone">
<option value="10">Australia/Sydney</option>
<option value="11">Australia/Melbourne<option>
<option value="12">Australia/Brisbane<option>
</select>
```

I want to remove all the options element so I can start repopulating options with completely different option.

How do I do that? Looking at the Jquery mobile, didn't see any SELECTMENU methods that I can utilise.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for removing all the options you can simply use:

```
$('#zone').find('option').remove();
```

You would also need to refresh selectmenu to see the modified select:

```
$('#zone').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

and for appending new values:

```
$('#zone').append("<option value='13'>Australia/Perth</option");
```